# EMR and how it works?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

If light is an oscillating EM field, does that mean when an electron emits light it would emit the light in all directions?  If so, why is it things can block or absorb light? How does something block or absorb an EM field?  By doing so wouldn’t that disrupt the field and create some sort of gap in the field that wouldn’t align properly with the current position of the electron?  How can we describe light as a “ray” when it goes in all directions?

Comment: A reasonably complete answer to a question this broad would have to be as long and detailed as an optics textbook. A librarian at any large urban library should be able to help you find several books appropriate to your level of math and science education.

Comment: All comes down to - superposition of all waves, phase difference between the incident and emmitted wave.

Comment: An electron emits photons in every direction.

Answer (score 0):

Light is a part of electromagnetic radiation, which also includes, for example, infrared (colloquially called heat radiation) and X-rays.

As you correctly pointed out, electron emits light, or more correctly EM radiation. This always occurs in the form of photons and happens again and again when the electron has been excited by an energy supply.

Photons, called quanta ("light quanta") by Einstein, are units of quite different energy (photons with higher energy content are also emitted by excited protons). All photons have the following properties in common:

- they are indivisible from the time of their emission to the time of their absorption
- they all travel through space at the same speed, the speed of light
- the quanta have an electric and a magnetic field component, both perpendicular to the direction of motion and also perpendicular to each other. If in a Cartesian coordinate system X is the direction of motion, then Y and Z are the axes along which the magnetic field and the electric field are aligned, respectively.
- the two field components oscillate sinusiodally.

`when an electron emits light it would emit the light in all directions?` A body constantly emits countless photons in all directions through its excited surface electrons. Each electron by itself emits photons from the surface of the body away from this surface.

`If so, why is it things can block or absorb light?` The stream of emitted photons could then hit the surface of a body again and its surface electrons absorb the photons. In turn, it re-emits a portion of the photons. The rest is transformed into lattice vibrations and other excited states and ends up as infrared radiation.

`How can we describe light as a “ray” when it goes in all directions?` A beam is the directional radiation of a small cross-section in one direction. This is realised with light, for example, through a small opening in an enclosed light source or through a laser (which also has a small exit opening). In this way, the stream of photons is more or less directed in one direction.